# ImportError: No module named 'celery'

Tags: python, celery, virtualenv

Encoutered this error message while following directions from [this guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#calling-the-task):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/user/celery/tasks.py", line 1, in <module> from celery import Celery
ImportError: No module named 'celery'`
```

I was using a virtual environment with celery installed.

My commands goes like this:

```
#ran the celery app
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info

#then on another terminal
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ python
$ from tasks import add'
```

Did I miss something here?

Comment: Can you list out all the commands you typed out before you saw this error?

Comment: Do you get the same error if your script is not in a directory called `celery`?

Comment: @cdarke: tried your suggestion. I renamed the directory to "celerio", same error

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: it goes like this:
'#ran the celery app
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info'

'#then on another terminal
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ python
$ from tasks import add'

Comment: Well then, can you do the same thing but do `import celery` in your python REPL and then paste the output of `print celery.__file__` please?

Comment: Also, when you have multi line stuff to say, it would be clearer to update the question rather than post it in a comment. Easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that celery 3.1 is not compatible with Python 3.4.3

I switched to using Python 2.7.3, now the import works